# Codeigniter form validation in AJAX form submission

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation

please help me.

I've been working recently in Codeigniter form validation without using AJAX and working fine, i just need to add `$form_error` to each field and everything just put on there. So, i am not good in javascript and really confusing how to show the errors response to each input field because when i am using AJAX the only idea i have is putting the response in a selector like `$(#error-info)`

This is my work so far

in my controller

```
$this->_rules();

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
            $msg = array(
            'name' => form_error('name'),
            'phone' => form_error('phone'),
            'email' => form_error('email')
        );
        echo json_encode($msg);
```

and my ajax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#frm').submit(function(){
  $.post($('#frm').attr('action'), $('#frm').serialize(), function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  }, 'json');
  return false;     
   });
});
</script>
```

the response look like this

```
{"name":"<small class=\"text-danger\">The name field is required.<\/small>","phone":"<small class=\"text-danger\">The phone field is required.<\/small>","email":"<small class=\"text-danger\">The email field is required.<\/small>"}
```

Please give me a hint. What a possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (haven't tested):

PHP

```
$msg = array(
    'name' => form_error('name'),
    'phone' => form_error('phone'),
    'email' => form_error('email')
);

echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'response' => $msg));
```

AJAX

We assume that the indexes of the `$msg` array matches an actual id e.g. `id='email'` so we can propagate the error messages after the field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frm').submit(function () {
        $.post($('#frm').attr('action'), $('#frm').serialize(), function (res) {
            var data = JSON.parse(res);
            if (data.status == 'error') {
                $.each(data.response, function(item_id, item_error_msg) {
                    $('#'+item_id).after().html(item_error_msg);
                });
            } else {
                alert(data.response);
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```